# How to UPDATE a MySQL table from an HTML form with PHP PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I’m working on an app and I am getting stuck updating values in a MySQL database table.

When I use the single value version of the *name* attribute (i.e. `name="value1"`) everything works fine. But, when I use the array syntax (`name="value[]"`) for the `name` attribute I get an error.

The error occurs right here:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE students SET value=value+{$_POST['value']}");
```

The error is:

> Error: Notice: Array to string conversion on line 8
>   Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'

This is my *PDOStatement::execute* statement.

```
$stmt->execute(array("value", $_POST['value']));
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input class="input" id="id1" name="value[]" type="range">
<input class="input" id="id2" name="value[]" type="range">
<input class="input" id="id3" name="value[]" type="range">
```

The columns in my table are named *value1*, *value2*, *value3* and so on.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Never use anything from $_POST directly! *Sanitize* and *validate* all user input. What you see below is for demonstration purposes only. Without a `WHERE` clause in your query, the entire table will be updated.

---

When you do this in your HTML `<input>` elements:

```
name="value[]"
```

`$_POST` will receive an array for the `$_POST` element *value*. Thus,

```
$_POST['value'] //resolves to an array.
```

That is why you are getting an error (Error: *Notice: Array to string conversion*) when you do this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET `value` = `value` +{$_POST['value']}");
```

Braces `{}` are typically used during string interpolations within double quotes. Your code is trying to turn an array in to a string.

You might try this instead:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET `value1` = `value1` + ?");
```

Or, this ...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET `value1` = `value1` + :value1");
```

Do not put user input directly into a prepared statement. The [PHP PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) manual page states.

> Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the
>   PDOStatement::execute() method. The SQL statement can contain zero or
>   more named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers for which
>   real values will be substituted when the statement is executed. You
>   cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the
>   same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style. Use these
>   parameters to bind any user-input, **do not include the user-input**
>   **directly in the query**.

You need to do some processing of the array `$_POST['values']` first. ***Sanitizing*** and ***validating*** the data is highly advisable and a best practice.

The data for your `<input>` elements is actually here.

```
$_POST['values'][0]  //Resolves to a string.
$_POST['values'][1]  //Resolves to a string.
$_POST['values'][2]  //Resolves to a string.
```

The error *Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'* suggests that you should use the name of an actual column in your table. By your own words, those field names are `value1`, `value2`, and `value3`.

When you use `PDOStatement::execute`, you can do this just to see if things are working in the `?` way....

```
$stmt->execute([$_POST['values'][0]])                   //PHP 5.4+
```

Or

```
$stmt->execute(array([$_POST['values'][0]))             //PHP 5.3 and below
```

If you used named parameters, you can try this.

```
$stmt->execute(['value1' => $_POST['values'][0]])       //PHP 5.4+
```

Or

```
$stmt->execute(array('value1' => [$_POST['values'][0])) //PHP 5.3 and below
```

.... but I call that ***living dangerously***. *Sanitize and validate your inputs first*.

If you ever get to the point of using [MySQL stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) (say, for an e-commerce site) with your PDO prepared statements, look up [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (must use variables with this) and [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) (can use general values, like string literals).

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $variable); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Or ...

```
$stmt->bindValue(:name, $variable);
$stmt->execute();
```

`$stmt->bindParam(1, $variable);` or `$stmt->bindParam(:name, $variable);`  are mostly useful for using `IN/OUT` arguments with stored procedures.

Be careful. You will end up updating the entire table because there is no `WHERE` condition in your query! But, if you want all records to have the same value, that's how you can do it. :-) What would [Edgar F. Codd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) say?

While it is possible to use a loop to solve the problem of using all three supposed $_POST['value'] elements, one still needs to ask why the entire table would need to be updated for each iteration.

I edited your answer to look like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) && is_array($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value']) && (count($_POST['value']) === 3)){
    foreach($_POST['value'] as $key => $value) {
        $num = ($key + 1);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET value{$num} = ? + value{$num}");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $value);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

While not comprehensive, at least better checking is being done. But, something like this could be better.

```
if(!isset($_POST['value']) || !is_array($_POST['value']) || empty($_POST['value']) || (count($_POST['value']) !== 3)){
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Something is wrong with the input in $_POST.");
}

foreach($_POST['value'] as $key => $value) {
    $num = ($key + 1);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET value{$num} = ? + value{$num}");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $value);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comprehensive reaction. I didn't mentioned that the input must increase the database values. However, this is how I get it to work.

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    if(is_array($_POST['value'])) {
    foreach($_POST['value'] as $key => $value) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE students SET value".($key+1)." = ? + value".($key+1)." ");
    $stmt->execute(array($value));

   } 
}
```

With thanks to the guy who removed his answer but he give me the inspiration!

Comment: You have not filtered and validated the input. Even the indexes to the array are user input (they can be manipulated by the user with developer tools). You are making too many assumptions, which defeats the purpose of using prepared statements altogether. If you made an expression $tempVar = $key +1 one time, you would not have to repeat the addition operation three time per iteration.

Comment: You either use `PDOStatement::bindParam` / `PDOStatement::bindValue, but not in combination with `PDOStatement::execute` with arguments. It's one or the other.

Comment: Going directly from $_POST (even using a loop) into a query is never best practice.

Comment: Checking that `$_POST['value']` is set and that `$_POST['value']` is an array, does not check to see if the array has all the elements you expect. In other words, the array could be *empty* (which will pass the `isset()` test), or it could have ten elements.

Comment: Also, this query updates the entire table for each iteration because there is no `WHERE` clause. If that is what you want to happen, fine.

Comment: Hi Anthony,

I really appreciate your input and understand you want the best practice for a solution.But I was searching for to make it work. I’m not the programmer you are. And youre right about ‘PDOStatement::bindParam / PDOStatement::bindValue, but not in combination with PDOStatement::execute` with arguments.’ 
So I lost the '$stmt->bindParam(($key+1)', $value); And validation/security is the next step.
Thanks!

Comment: If you only need to use one value in your query, you are better off using `PDOStatement::bindValue`. Why make the computer create an array simply to get one value to the prepared statement?

Comment: I’ve a form with lot of range value[](value1, value2 enz.) send to the columns(value1, value2 enz.) to sum/increase with the values in the database.

Comment: @Ok, I edited your answer to make it a bit more concise.

Comment: Hi Anthony, A few day ago you give this answer which were great. Only now I have another question and you mention it before. How do I add a where clause. I get an error on this:
'
foreach($_POST['value'] as $key => $value) {
    $num = ($key + 1);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `students` SET value{$num} = ? + value{$num} WHERE 'name'=:name");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $value);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $name);
    $stmt->execute( array('name' => $name, 'value' => $value) );
}

Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters 

Thanks!